# IIf Statement only manipulating part of the data in a field

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, iif

I created an IIf statement in a MS Access query, to fill null spaces in a particular field. The statement in only affecting some of the data, but not all. Why would it only work on a certain percentage of the records?

```
Field:Line_off_Date

Table:Claims

Criteria:IIf(IsNull("Line_off_Date "),"1/1/1900"
```

Here is the official Sql  after delimiting:

```
SELECT Claims.Line_off_Date 
FROM Claims
WHERE (((Claims.Line_off_Date)=IIf("Line_off_Date IsNull",#1/1/1900#,"Line_off_Date ")));
```

I can't screen shot onto this site, but I could give a mock up representation:

Line_off_Date

12/23/2013
12/23/2013
5/16/2010
1/1/1900
1/1/1900

12/10/2000
11/4/2008

This is listed as a column, with a space between 1/1/1900 and 12/10/2000. When I post it here, it turns into a paragraph. I hope this helps in some way...

Comment: Is is possible that the other records have a space instead of being actually null? Check the length of the fields for those records

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure about your goal, but this looks like something where you could use the [Nz Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/nz-function-HA001228890.aspx).

```sql
Criteria: Nz(Line_off_Date, "1/1/1900")
```

If you want `IIf` instead, try it this way ...

```sql
Criteria: IIf(Line_off_Date Is Null, "1/1/1900", Line_off_Date)
```

Note those suggestions assume `Line_off_Date` is text datatype.  If it is actually Date/Time, delimit the value with `#` instead of quotes.

```sql
Criteria: Nz(Line_off_Date, #1/1/1900#)
Criteria: IIf(Line_off_Date Is Null, #1/1/1900#, Line_off_Date)
```

I'm more confused after seeing your `WHERE` clause ...

```sql
WHERE (((Claims.Line_off_Date)=IIf("Line_off_Date IsNull",#1/1/1900#,"Line_off_Date ")));
```

Aside from the issues of quoting and so forth, I think the logic is faulty.  If you say *"show me rows where `Line_off_Date` = something other than what is stored in `Line_off_Date`"*, you may not get any rows back.

I think you need a different approach.  If you need more help, show us a brief set of sample data and your desired output based on those data.

Based on the comment discussion, my understanding is you don't really want to *filter* the result set based on `Line_off_Date` --- which means this is not a `WHERE` clause issue.  Instead, you want to retrieve `Line_off_Date` values, but substitute `#1900-1-1#` for any which are Null.  If that is correct, do the transformation with a field expression  in the `SELECT` clause.

```sql
SELECT Nz(Claims.Line_off_Date, #1900-1-1-#) AS Line_off_Date_adjusted 
FROM Claims;
```

Comment: I checked the record length, and that seems to be okay. I just tried to use the Nz function you suggested, but I got the mismatch data type error, which seems very puzzling...

Comment: That's my fault for offering a guess based on limited information.  Please revise your question to include the SQL from the query which gives you that error message.

Comment: One of the fields is "Line_off_Date", some of the records had no value after import, which I do not know why.? So, to get everything to work with a join that I was working on, I have to have it as date/time. I just tried to delimit, as per your suggestion, with the IIf, but it still returns a null value for some of the records. Does that make sense? Not your fault; I appreciate ALL of your help! Here is the SQL: SELECT Claims.Line_off_Date
FROM Claims
WHERE (((Claims.Line_off_Date)=IIf("Line_off_Date IsNull",#1/1/1900#,"Line_off_Date ")));

Comment: @autumntiger: You have speech marks around `...IIf("Line_off_Date IsNull",...` in the code you dropped in the comment - try removing the speech marks.

Comment: @autumntiger: Actually, scratch that - your line is gibberish, that's why there are speech marks around it.  There should be a space between `Is` and `Null`: `SELECT Claims.Line_off_Date FROM Claims WHERE (((Claims.Line_off_Date)=IIf([Line_off_Date] Is Null, #1/1/1900#, [Line_off_Date])));`

Comment: I tried putting the space between Is and Null, but it still did not return a value for the last 1,990 records. What is even stranger, is that I just got an error message that said I had exceeded the system!?!? Very interesting...

Comment: Please explain, in English instead of SQL, your `Line_off_Date` selection criteria.  What specific conditions must that field satisfy to be returned by your query?

Comment: Basically, if it has no value in it at all (which is a date/time datatype), I want it to be filled in with 1/1/1900. Last week you were very helpful in a question I posted about joining a query and a table, and coming up with a datatype mismatch; this is a continuation of that issue....does that help?

Comment: @HansUp It would not let me do a screen shot. I could give a mock up representation:

Comment: No.  If I still haven't understood what you're aiming for after all this effort, it's not rational for me to invest more of my time.

Comment: I do understand, and I appreciate the help. I'm sure it is something small that is missing, and it will make itself known at some point. All of your posts were helpful and enlightening, and will aid me in th future.

Comment: Thank you for your gracious response.  However I think you should un-accept this answer because it did not solve your problem.  Save the accept as motivation/reward for whoever can figure out the answer you need.